# How to change the display style of webform in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I have made a form using Drupal 7 webform, but I want to change the display style of the form. Please let me know how to edit the display. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Override webform-form.tpl.php. http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!templates!webform-form.tpl.php/7